# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF on line 4

Tags: php

```
<?php    
Include('connect.php')

If(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])!='')
{
If($_REQUEST['firstname']=='' || $_REQUEST['email']=='' ||     $_REQUEST['password']==''|| $_REQUEST['lastname']=='' || $_REQUEST['username']==='' )
{
Echo "please fill the empty field.";
```

I am getting this error. What am I doing wrong? I looked into it twice. It should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon at the end of your include statement.

Change:

```
include('connect.php')
```

To:

```
include('connect.php');
```

The reason you're seeing the `if` as a cause for the error, is because what you have done. Is missed out the vital point of PHP, Which tells the interpreter to stop processing the current command (hence the semi-colon). So, PHP is still expecting to process the `include`, so is completely confused when it comes to the following line. Thus throwing an error on what can be seen as the wrong line.

Comment: Got that sorted out. The main issue what I am facing is with the registration form. Check the edit I made to the question. Its giving this error: "There is some problem in inserting record".

Comment: @Devlin: please revert your question back to its original state. If you have a new problem, then please ask a new question. Please check and feel free to contribute to [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309237/dealing-with-edited-questions/309238#309238) on this very topic.

Comment: @Daryl Sorry for that. I reverted the question back.